# If input:radio click checked radio

Tags: jquery, input, radio-button

How do I detect when a radio button is checked?

**HTML :**

```
<label><input type="radio" name="test">One</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="test">Two</label>
```

I want to perform a certain function whenever the user picks an option from my radio button

I tried something like:

```
$("input:radio").on("change", function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).attr('checked', false)
        // do some more...

    }
});
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/A5EzU/

As the 'clear' debug statement shows on the fiddle, once clicked it looks like it is clicked all the time.

Comment: Detect if radio is checked , Sorry for bad expand :( @OneTrickPony

Comment: Try in my demo , it's doesn't work @OneTrickPony

Comment: You want checkboxes. Period.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Oh ! I can't do with :radio  ?

Comment: looks like it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/czUcj/

Comment: No, radio buttons always have exactly one option selected (except initially if no default is provided, but that should be avoided). Checkboxes on the other side support 0..n selected elements. If you want 0 or 1 keep using checkboxes but add some JS to deselect the previously selected item or use radio buttons and add a "nothing" radio button.

Comment: Also, note that `.prop()` is preferable over `.attr()` for this. Take a look at the [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) jQuery docs for an explanation as to why.

Comment: Thanks you all , So I will use checkbox :)

Comment: @OneTrickPony He wants to be able to uncheck a radio, after it's been checked.

Comment: So answer this "Use checkbox" right ? Please vote close my question , Thanks you all :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try checkboxes instead of radio buttons where only one can be checked at the same time.

Html:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" />One</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" />Two</label>
```

JS:

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function(){
  $("input:checkbox").not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Fiddle example: [click](http://jsfiddle.net/pBcu5/3/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

HTML

```
<label><input type="radio" name="test" id="one">One</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="test" id="two">Two</label>

<code></code>
```

JS

```
$("input:radio").on("change", function(){
if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('code').html('clear !');
    $(this).attr("id");
    $('code').append($(this).attr("id"));
    $(this).attr(':checked', false)
    if($(this).attr("id")=="one")
    {
        alert("One");
    }
    else
        alert("two");
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amitagrawal/A5EzU/3/)

Comment: -1 for all the wrong things in this post: NO-OP: `$(this).attr("id");`  // use prop and remove the colon: `$(this).attr(':checked', false)` // do not combine {} and non-{} bodies in the same statement // use `this.id` // besides that, it does not work.